# Type mismatch using split VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have the following code and it gives me the error Type mismatch for the line of code «Split_dt_2 = Split(Split_dt_1, ",")». I'm not able to run through the code with F8 because it gives me the error right away so i can't give the exact value of «Split_dt_1» but it's always a date which has that form : [11/1/2019,12/1/2019].

My goal would be to obtain :
y_Dest = 2019 and m_Des = 11

```
 Sub import_Redeem_Spread()    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\106400\OneDrive\Documents\FTT\CDOPT_AB.xlsm"
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
    Set wksSource = Workbooks("CDOPT_AB.xlsm").Sheets(2)
    Set wksDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)



 Dim Split_dt_1() As String
    Dim Split_dt_2() As String
    Dim Split_dt_3() As String
    Dim Split_dt_4() As String


    nbRows = wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nbDates = wksDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To nbRows
        If wksSource.Cells(i, 16) = "CPG Taux Fixe" Then
            For m = 7 To nbDates
 Split_dt_1 = wksDest.Cells(m, 2)
        Split_dt_2 = Split(Split_dt_1, ",")
        Split_dt_3 = Split_dt_2(0)
        Split_dt_4 = Split(Split_dt_3, "[")
        y_Dest = Right(Split_dt_4(1), 4)
        m_Dest = Left(Split_dt_4(1), 2)
        y_source = Left(Cells(I, 3), 4)
        m_Source = Right(Cells(I, 3), 2)

                If y_Dest = m_Dest & y_Source = m_Source Then
                    For n = 4 To 15
                        wksDest.Cells(m, n) = wksSource.Cells(i, n)
                    Next n
                End If
            Next m
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

I tried «Dim Split_dt_2() As Variant» but it does noes solve the problem

and I tried

```
Split_dt_1 = wksDest.Cells(m, 2).value
Split_dt_2 = Split(Split_dt_1, ",")
```

and it still doesn't work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `Variant` when using `Split` to create the array instead of `Dim`ing it as an array.

Comment: `If y_Dest = m_Dest & y_Source = m_Source Then` - you want `And` instead of `&`.

Comment: Note that `Split` returns a *zero-based* array so `Split_dt_2(1)` returns the 2nd element, not the first.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be convenient to separate the code that deletes "[" and "]" into a comma and then work.

Comment: @braX i'm not quite sure to understang the change you want me to try?
 Dim Split_dt_1() As Variant
    Dim Split_dt_2() As Variant
    Dim Split_dt_3() As Variant
    Dim Split_dt_4() As Variant

This doesn't work.

Comment: `Dim Split_dt_1 As Variant`

Comment: Thanks @BigBen I had forgot tis one so : Split_dt_2(0)

Comment: @braX it worked, thanks! I had never seen a dim without the brackets.. what is the general rule to know when to use brackets or not?

Comment: it only works with `Variant` types... you can turn them into arrays if the function you use returns an array

Comment: @BraX Ok perfect thanks. How do i submit you comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Variant` when using `Split` to create the array instead of `Dim`ing it as a `String` array.

A `Variant` will take on the properties of an `Array` when the function you are using returns an `Array`.

```
Dim Split_dt_1 As Variant
Split_dt_1 = Split(wksDest.Cells(m, 2), ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch assigning the Arrays and all the intermediate steps altogether:

```
y_Dest = Year(Split(Split(wksDest.Cells(m, 2), ",")(0), "[")(0))
```

There are times when having those intermediate steps helps, but IMO, this isn't one of them.

Comment: I know but i'm usually not good enough to eliminate the intermediate steps :

I tried it and it gives me the error type mismatch. I did change a little something though in the code instead of "Year" it's "right.

I tried this :
y_Dest = right((Split(Split(wksDest.Cells(m, 2), ",")(0), "[")(0)),4)

Out of curiosity : if I eliminate intermediate steps will the code run faster?